# CIR model: is the short rate really non-central $\chi^2$ distributed?

Tags: stochastic-processes, short-rate

Probably simple question. Consider the [CIR (1985)](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1911242?origin=crossref&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) model for interest rates
$$
dr = k(\theta - r)dt + \sigma \sqrt{r}dz
$$
Then it is known in closed form the conditional pdf $f(r(s),s|r(t),t)$ ($s \geq t$) 
$$
f(r(s),s|r(t),t) = ce^{-u-v}\left(\frac{v}{u}\right)^{q/2}I_{q}(2\sqrt{uv})
$$
where
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
c &=\frac{2k}{\sigma^{2}\left(1-e^{-k(s-t)}\right)}\\
u &=cr(t)e^{-k(s-t)}\\
v &=cr(s)\\
q &=\frac{2k\theta}{\sigma^2}-1
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
and $I_{q}(\cdot)$ is a modified Bessel function of the first kind of order $q$.

Then authors state:

> << The distribution function is the non central chi-square $\chi^2[2 c r(s); 2q + 2, 2u]$, with $2q+2$ degrees of freedom and parameter of non centrality $2u$ proportional to the current spot rate. >>

Then my questions:

1) Is it correct to say that what is (conditionally on $r(t)$) non-central $\chi^2$ distributed is the variable $2cr(s)$?

I can answer by my own to this question: Since the conditional expectation $E(r(s)|r(t))$ and variance $Var(r(s)|r(t))$ are provided in the paper (Eq. 19), it'easy to check the validity of 1) verifying that:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
(2q+2) + (2u) &= E(2cr(s)|r(t)) = 2c E(r(s)|r(t))\\ 
2[(2q+2) + 2(2u)] &= Var(2cr(s)|r(t)) = 4c^2Var(r(s)|r(t))
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where l.h.s. of both equations are expressions for the first two moments of a non-central $\chi^2$ variable with $2q+2$ and parameter of non-centrality $2u$ (you may want to check [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution)).

2) If 1), which is the conditional distribution of $r(s)$ alone? Is it still non-central $\chi^2$?

I want to be crystal clear: we know that $2cr(s) \stackrel{|r(t)}{\sim} \chi^2(2q+2,2u)$. Moreover, we know in closed form the (conditional on $r(t)$) pdf of $r(s)$ (the $f(r(s),s|r(t),t)$ above)... but then, is $r(s)$ a *KNOWN* random variable ($|r(t)$)? In particular, is it still non-cenral $\chi^2$ distributed? (*)

Thanks for your attention

(*) I'm afraid $r(s)$ cannot still be non-central $\chi^2$ since this would imply that the non-central $\chi^2$ would be close w.r.t. scaling of the variable, and - I'm not sure - this should not be the case.

Comment: With $s\ge t$ are you suee that the parameters are as you describe? With $s\ge t$ I would expect the whole thing to be conditional on $r_t$ and thus having $r_t$ in the parameters.

Comment: Thanks @Richard Yes dependency w.r.t. $r_t$ is in the parameter $u$, and both $c$ and $u$ depend on time $t$, $s$, and their difference $s-t$. You may check equations (18) and (19) in paper.

Comment: I've added details, definitions needed are above. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer this I sum up a paragraph of "Interest rate models - An Introduction" by A.Cairns:
For $i=1,\ldots,d$ consider the OU-processes
$$
dX^i_t = -\frac 12 \alpha X^i_t dt + \sqrt{\alpha} dW^i_t.
$$
Looking at the squared radius $R_t = \sum_{i=1}^d (X^i_t)^2 $ (in $\mathbb{R}^d$) of this process we get by Ito:
$$
dR_t = \sum_{i=1}^d  (2 X^i_t dX^i_t) + d \alpha dt.
$$
Using the definition of $R_t$ introducing a new Brownian motion $B_t$ we get in distribution that that
$$
dR_t =  \alpha (d - R_t) dt + \sqrt{4 \alpha R_t} dB_t.
$$
Defining $r_t = R_t/\theta$ with $\theta = 4\alpha/\sigma^2$ this is the CIR model.
This gives a nice geometric interpretation.
I am aware that not all details are covered here.

Recall the definition of the non central chi-squared distribution. Let 
$$
R = \sum_{i=1}^d (W_i + \delta_i)^2
$$
and $\lambda = \sum_{i=1}^d \delta_i^2$, then $R$ has a non-central chi-squared distribution with $d$ degrees of freedom and non-centrality parameter $\lambda$.

Since the $X_i^t$ above are all normally distributed with variance $1- e^{-\alpha t}$ we see that $R_t/(1- e^{-\alpha t})$ has non-central chi-squared distribution. Finally we have that for $d = 4 \alpha \mu/\sigma^2$ that $4 \alpha r_t/(\sigma^2 (1- e^{-\alpha t}))$ has a non-central chi-squared distribution with $d$ degrees of freedom and non-centrality parameter $\lambda = 4 \alpha r_0/(\sigma^2 (1- e^{-\alpha t}))$.

Conditionally on $r_t$ replace $r_0$ by $r_t$.

The answers then are:
i) Yes, the variable that has non-central chi-squared distribution is the complicated expression that you mention.

ii) Only this complicated expression is non-central chi-squared distributed - $r_s$ itself is not. As you see in the link the non-central chi-squared distribution relates to standardized Gaussians (variance equals 1). Maybe the [Generalized chi-squared distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_chi-squared_distribution) could be of help. But I don't know this.