# How to extract parameters in the CIR model from data?

Tags: interest-rates

I want to extract CIR parameters from monthly LIBOR data in the EULER-MARYAMA method in MATLAB language.
I found the data but I can't extract parameters from it.
What is the process? What is the formula?

Answer (score 2):

As You Know, CIR model is the square root process given by the following stochastic differential equation
$$d{{r}_{t}}=\kappa (\theta -{{r}_{t}})dt+\sigma \sqrt{{{r}_{t}}}d{{W}_{t}}$$ 
Let $\Theta=(\kappa,\theta,\sigma)$. It is well-known that conditional on a realized value of $r_t$, the random variable $2c_t\,r_{t+\Delta t}$  follows a non-central chi-square distribution with $d = 4\kappa\theta/\sigma^2$ degrees of freedom and non-centrality parameter
$2c_t\,r_te^{−κ\Delta t}$, where
$$c_t=\frac{2\kappa }{{{\sigma }^{2}}\,[1-{{e}^{-\kappa \Delta t}}]}$$
Indeed the density of $r_{t+\Delta t}$ is
$$P(r_{t+\Delta t}|r_t;\Theta)=c\,e^{-u-v}(\frac{u}{v})^{\frac{q}{2}}I_q(2\sqrt{uv})$$
where

$$\,\,\,u_t=c_t\,r_te^{−κ\Delta t}$$
$$v_t=c_t\,r_{t+\Delta t}$$
$$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,q=\frac{2\kappa\theta}{\sigma^2}-1$$
and $I_q(2\sqrt{uv})$ is modified Bessel function of the first kind and of order $q$. The transition density has been originally derived in [this](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/23178/demonstrate-that-a-square-root-process-is-non-central-chi-squared-distributed/27691#27691).

Parameter estimation is carried out on interest rate time series with N observations We consider equally spaced observations with $\Delta t$ time. **The likelihood** function for interest rate time series with $N$ observations is step
$$L(\Theta )=\prod\limits_{i=1}^{N-1}{P({{t}_{t+\Delta t}}}|\,{{r}_{t}}\,;\,\Theta )$$
It is computationally convenient to work with the log-likelihood function
$$\ln L(\Theta )=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N-1}{\ln P({{t}_{t+\Delta t}}}\,|{{r}_{t}}\,;\,\Theta )$$
from which we easily derive the log-likelihood function of the CIR process
$$\ln L(\Theta )=(N-1)\ln c+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N-1}{\left( -{{u}_{{{t}_{i}}}}-{{v}_{{{t}_{i}}}}+\frac{1}{2}q\,\ln \left( \frac{{{v}_{{{t}_{i+1}}}}}{{{u}_{{{t}_{i}}}}} \right)+\ln {{I}_{q}}(\sqrt{2{{u}_{{{t}_{i}}}}{{v}_{{{t}_{i+1}}}}} \right)}$$
You can find maximum likelihood estimates $\widehat{\Theta }$ of parameter
vector $\Theta$ by maximizing the log-likelihood function last equation over its parameter space:
$$\widehat{\Theta }=arg\,\underset{\Theta }{\mathop{max}}\,\,\ln \,L(\Theta )$$