# Derivation of the distribution for a CIR process

Tags: interest-rates, stochastic-processes, term-structure, cox-ingersoll-ross, transition-distribution

**Where is it possible to find a complete derivation of the distribution of a CIR process?**

There is a number of papers that claim that it is a **noncentrical chi-squared** distribution.
However, I cannot find anything where a detailed explanation of its derivation is given.
The starting point is the paper by Feller (1951) that deals with the PDE that is exactly the Kolmogorov Forward Equation / Fokker-Planck Equation for the CIR model. Nevertheless, that paper does not provide any explicit solution in the case where the so-called "Feller's condition" holds.
Other papers look incomplete or use other approaches. While the the most famous one (i.e. the transition probability derivation from a Kolgomogorov equation) seems unclear.

Comment: Hi. Maybe the answer to [this post](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/16107/cir-model-is-the-short-rate-really-non-central-chi2-distributed) is what you are looking for?